# How do you get a value of a variable of an other object of the same class?

Tags: java, get, set, getter-setter

I'm working on a little game to learn java.
Currently I created a Sphere, a Player and a Game class ( + Main class to run).
I want the shpere to know, whether it collides with the player or not.

First thing I tried was the Get and Set thing, but the problem is, that I have to create a Player-Object
in the Sphere-class to acces the Get-Method of the Players Position.

As it's a new object, it's not the same as the Object in my Game-Class, so it doesn't change when moving.

Comment: *"...but the problem is, that I have to create a Player-Object in the Sphere-class..."* -- no, that is not true at all and in fact will mess things up, since in all likelihood, that newly created Player will not be the same Player instance that is acting in the Game class. Better instead to have Game see where Player and Sphere are located and to either observe for collisions and report and control the effects or to have Game notify all objects of the locations of other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Think who is the responsibility to check for collision. It can be confusing but logically you need a Game class where you will have access to both Player and a Sphere objects. There you can have update method (which is executed in some time frame in a loop) and there you can check the positions of the two objects if they collide. So this mean that the positions must be kept inside in Player for player object and in Sphere for Sphere object.

Answer (score 0):

add a reference to the player object to the sphere object

```
    class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player();
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere();
        sphere.setPlayer(player);
    
        Game game = new Game(player, sphere);
        game.start();
      }
    }
```

Inside the sphere object you can now access the players position using the reference

Or you do something like this.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.start();
    }
}

class Game {
    private Player player;
    private Sphere sphere;
    
    public Game(){
        player = new Player();
        sphere = new Sphere();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        // implement game loop or whatever
        // to find out about the colliding state use isColliding
    }
    
    private boolean isColliding() {
        // implement logic to calculate colliding state using player.getPosition() and sphere.getPosition()
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, but it would be better if both `player` and `sphere` were instances within the `game` instance. This would allow them to both address each other by using the `game` instance. Upon creating the player/sphere instance, the argument `this` could be used to tell them about their parent, the `game` instance. *They just have to refrain from utilizing this early reference to the `game` instance right away!*